# Slick + scala: get autoincremented id after saving

Tags: scala, slick

I'm saving entity like this:

```
def addUser(user: User) = {
  val future = db.run(DBIO.seq(
    userQueue += user,
    userQueue .result.map(println)
  ))
  Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
}
```

(where userQueue is TableQuery)
And user do not get new autoincremented ID. 
How can I get in automaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this: 
def addUser(user: User) = {
    val future = db.run(userQueue returning userQueue.map(_.id) += user )
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
}
```

For more details: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#index-16